# Is there a way to indicate to C# nullability analysis that an instance variable will never be null after a certain method runs?

Tags: c#, annotations, nullable, nullability

I've got a class with an instance var that can be null, and that class has a method that initializes that var. Broadly simplified, it looks a bit like this

```cs
#nullable enable

class SomeClass
{
    private Foo? someObject;

    private void InitSomeObject()
    {
        someObject = new Foo() { ... }
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        if (someObject?.Id == null)
            InitSomeObject();

        Console.WriteLine(someObject.Id) // <-- nullability warning here, "someObject may be null"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to indicate to the compiler that `someObject` is not null once `InitSomeObject()` has been called?

Answer (score 0):

Hm...

maybe not the answer what you want or...

Why you not remove the nullable from Foo and initalize it with FooEmpty?

```
class FooEmpty : Foo
{

}

class SomeClass
{
    private Foo someObject = new FooEmpty(); // better singelton

    private void InitSomeObject()
    {
        someObject = new Foo() { ... }
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        if (someObject is FooEmpty)
            InitSomeObject();

        Console.WriteLine(someObject.Id) 
    }
}
```

or you have a Empty Flag in Foo itself

```cs
class Foo
{

   public bool IsEmpty => SomeProperty == false && StringFoo == string.Empty;
}

class SomeClass
{
    private Foo someObject = new Foo(); // better singelton

    private void InitSomeObject()
    {
        someObject = new Foo() { ... }
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        if (someObject.IsEmpty)
            InitSomeObject();

        Console.WriteLine(someObject.Id) 
    }
}
```

Comment: This workaround removes the nullability warning, true, but it doesn't answer my actual question. Thanks anyway!